# Build Select widget in Bokeh using data frames

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I have a data frame df with column "location" (few cells with no value) -

```
location
US
India

US
Japan
US

India
```

I want to create a Single Selection Widget using bokeh with the values contained in Location column. I am writing below code -

```
location = Select(title="Location", value="All",
           options=df["location"].unique())
```

This gives me an error -

```
ValueError: expected an element of List(Either(String, Tuple(String, 
String))), got array(['US', 'India', 'EMEA', nan, 'Japan'], 
dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your pandas series into a list.

```
options=df["location"].unique().tolist()
```